# How can I set the value from Firebase in EditText?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

**How to set value (name) in EditText?**

```
"users": [
    "-KTYWvZG4Qn9ZYTc47O6" : {


      "name" : "my name"
    }
}
```

**I did it but**

```
package **.****;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.EditText;

import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

import ****.****.m_Model.Update_user1;



public class Update_a  extends AppCompatActivity {


    private  EditText name111;
   private DatabaseReference mFirebaseDatabase;
    private FirebaseDatabase mFirebaseInstance;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.Update__activity);




        myname111 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editext2);
        mFirebaseInstance = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
   mFirebaseDatabase = mFirebaseInstance.getReference("users");
        String userId = mFirebaseDatabase.push().getKey();

        mFirebaseDatabase.child(userId).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                Update_user1 model = dataSnapshot.getValue(Update_user1.class);

             myname111.setText(model.getname());


            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }


        });




    }
```

**Update_user1.class**

```
package **.****.m_Model;



public class Update_user1 {


    public String name;


    public Update_user1() {
    }
    public Update_user1(String name) {
        this.name = name;


    }

    public String getname() {

        return name;
    }
```

**But this not work**

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main  Process: ***.******, PID:
>   14980  java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual
>   method java.lang.String** .**.m_Model.Update_user1.getname() on a
>   null object reference
>                                 at ***.********.Update_u$1.onDataChange(Update_u.java:61)

Answer (score 2):

When you run this line:

```
  String userId = mFirebaseDatabase.push().getKey();
```

You generate a new so-called push ID. Next you attach a listener to a location based on this freshly created push ID.

```
    mFirebaseDatabase.child(userId).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
       ...
```

Since push IDs are statistically guaranteed to be unique, no value will exist at this location yet.

This means that `onDataChange()` will fire with an empty `DataSnapshot`:

```
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            Update_user1 model = dataSnapshot.getValue(Update_user1.class);

            myname111.setText(model.getname());
        }
```

Since the `DataSnapshot` is empty, `getValue()` will not be able to get a `Update_user1` and thus it will return `null`. And that leads to `model.getname()` calling `getname()` on a `null` object and thus throwing a `NullPointerException`.

The simplest way to handle the null is:

```
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                Update_user1 model = dataSnapshot.getValue(Update_user1.class);

                myname111.setText(model.getname());
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

the answer of frank is right as you really want to get the value of id doesn't exist yet and you must make the listener on the key that have the values so you don't have to know the hashkey of it

so you can make as follow

```
  mFirebaseDatabase.getReference("users")
            .addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                     Update_user1 model = dataSnapshot.getValue(Update_user1.class);

         myname111.setText(model.getname());
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                 // TODO
                }
            });
```